# How do I get the push footer trick to work in IE 8?

Tags: css, html, sticky-footer

I use this:

```
body {font-size:12px; font-family:"trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, sans-serif; background: #CCCCCC; word-wrap:break-word; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    height:auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -200px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    padding: 0px;
    border:0;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #FFFFFF;


.footer, .push {
    height: 200px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    position:absolute;
}
```

It looks as if it works fine in Firefox/Safari/Opera and IE 6 and 7 but not in 8.  What's missing or wrong?

Comment: can you please provide the HTML so people can test it out?

Answer (score 3):

Your code had some big holes in it, so I had to make some guesswork. You could test this one out, it seems to work the same on ff3, ie7 and ie8 that I tested.

I'm not sure if it's something that you wanted, but you really should provide an better example with your question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
html{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-size:12px; font-family:"trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, sans-serif; 
    background: #CCCCCC; 
    word-wrap:break-word; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    height:auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -200px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    padding: 0px;
    border:0;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.footer, 
.push {
    height: 200px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:red;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">Lorem</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer jabba jibba jubba hubba bubba dubba dibba dei</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that helps.